# Classic ASP Parallel Ajax Calls handled Serially by IIS (Session Lock?)

Tags: jquery, iis, asp-classic, synchronization

I'm maintaining an application written Classic ASP hosted on IIS 7.0. For a while I've observed a performance problem when we make 3 Ajax calls in a row that should happen in parallel, however it looks like IIS is executing them serially. It's a problem because the 1st Ajax call is a time-consuming call and there's no reason for the 2nd and 3rd queries to return before it.

What I think the problem is, is that during the calls, session objects are made and we're making modifications to the session in each of the calls. I believe IIS serializes the Ajax calls because of this.

My question is, is there a way to turn this off the lock because of the session but still keep the session "on" so that we can still read from it? I found the EnableSessionState attribute that I can use, however it completely disables the session, which I don't want to happen.

I know disabling the lock is probably not the best solution by a long shot, however stomping on variables between Ajax calls should be minimal. Any suggestions regarding how to tackle this problem are greatly appreciated.

mj

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no way to use session in parallel; they are per definition sequential since they run in the same "apartement" (STA).

If possible you could store your values in the application object as this runs in MTA (multithreaded). You could use a MSXML2.FreeThreadedDomDocument to store the values of each user (e.g. using a unique key stored in a cookie or something like that to fetch the users data).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to make changes to any of the session variables you could do the following:

Create a new page that has the session state turned off for that page with this:

```
<%@ EnableSessionState=False %>
```

Output the data you need from the session into your main page and then pass that data along in your jQuery calls.